# How to combine if statements in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I have this class and in the printVotes method I had to do the if statement every time to print each votes. Is  there any way to combine both the if statements. Could I print all the names of the candidates and the number of votes they got at the same time?

```
public class TestCandidate {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Canidate[] canidate = new Canidate[5];

        // create canidate
        canidate[0] = new Canidate("John Smith", 5000);
        canidate[1] = new Canidate("Mary Miller", 4000);        
        canidate[2] = new Canidate("Michael Duffy", 6000);
        canidate[3] = new Canidate("Tim Robinson", 2500);
        canidate[4] = new Canidate("Joe Ashtony", 1800);       

        printVotes(canidate) ;    
    }

    public static void printVotes(Canidate [] List)
    {
        double max;
        int index;

        if (List.length != 0)
        {

            index = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < List.length; i++)
            {

            }

            System.out.println(List[index]);
        }

        if (List.length != 0)
        {
            index = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < List.length; i++)
            {

            }
            System.out.println(List[index]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's preferred not to capitalize variable names in Java.  Especially since there are so many `List` types.

Comment: Why not loop through your `printVotes(canidate)` 5 times using a for loop? Each time sending a different array index value. Instead of looping through your method multiple times.

Comment: What's the difference between the two control flows?

Comment: Yes, I want to print all the names of the Candidates along with their votes. @Tdorno

Comment: The index for the second one is 1 and the first one is 0. @Lews Therin

Comment: Look, at my answer. If your class is structured as such.. it should do what you want.

Comment: Yes that is ok but I need to traverse through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a `List<Candidate> candidates;` and assuming that each candidate has a `List<Integer> Votes`:

```
    List<Integer> votes= new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
    for(Candidate c:candidates)
    {
       votes.add(c.GetVote()) ;
    } 
    for(Integer v:votes)
    {
      System.out.println(v);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way that i could traverse through the names and votes and then print them?

Comment: @user2337902 Why would you print them afterwards?

Comment: I meant like after I traverse through all of that I should return that number. @Lonenebula

Comment: So you want to loop through all candidate votes and after the loop print each votes? "What number"?

Comment: Yes that is what i meant.@LewsTherin

Comment: You can store the votes in a temporary list and then print all votes after I guess. But @Lonenebula is right, confusing :)

Comment: @user2337902 By looking at how you initialize the candidates, I assume each `Candidate` object stores a name, and a single int which tells the number of votes. Is this correct? In that case only one `for`-loop is sufficient: The one where you iterate through the candidates.

Comment: If I understand you right, I guess so: `tempVotesList.add(vote)`.. and after the iteration.. print `tempVotesList`.. but either way, you get the same result

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it that way of iterating. @LewsTherin

Comment: @user2337902 Look at the updated answer.. can you confirm that is what you want?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using two for loops. Wouldn't `for(Candidate c : candidates) { System.out.println(c.getVote()); }` give the same result? OP doesn't state the need to save the votes, but rather just display them.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri If you read the above comments, you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `Candidate` class's `toString()` method like so:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Candidate Name: " + this.name + "\nVotes: " + this.votes;
}
```

Then your `printVotes` method would look something like this:

```
public static void printVotes(Candidate[] list) {
    for(Candidate c : list) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

As someone else mentioned, avoid using capital letters in variable names especially in cases where words such as List are used. List is a collection type and can be easily confused.